# Image is not scaling down/up

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

somehow my image is not scaling down or up at all. I have seen many things on the internet but I could not solve it. W3schools told me to make it like this, with the formular-banner image.

```css
.formular-banner
{

    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="formular-banner">
                        <img src="koala.jpeg">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are defining settings for the **parent element** of the image, not for the image itself. So you can't expect that to have an effect on the image...

For the image itself, you also shouldn't use those settings, but instead of `max-width: 100%` (to make it the full width of the container), you should use `width: 100%`, plus a `max-width` that has the original width of the image in pixels, in order *not* to make it any bigger (i.e. distorted)  than the original image in case it's smaller (i.e. less wide) than the container.

So your CSS rule would be

```
.formular-banner > img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1240px; /* use the actual width of your image here */
    height: auto;
}
```

If the image is smaller than the container (which, as a div = block element) will have 100% width by default) and you want it to be centered, you can add this rule (for the container) which will horizontally center the image (as an inline element) inside the container:

```
.formular-banner {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this now: .formular-banner
{
 text-align: center;
 
 
}

.formular-banner img
{
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
 height: auto;
}

Comment: Yes, it works fine now! Thank you for your help. I have one last thing maybe you can help me. I have a footer on the bottom with the following code, but it hides the bottom of the img now. I want it to have some space between footer and img. footer
{
 background-color: salmon;
 padding: .4em;
 width: 100%;
 height: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 color: #F0EAD6;
 position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   position: fixed;
}

Comment: You should post that as a separate question and add all the code necessary to illustrate the problem (i.e. CSS *and* HTML code)